# When I write my results on a text file only one paragraph appears

Tags: python

I'm currently programming an app to gather information for me from websites using requests and BeautifulSoup. Now I am trying to place that information in a text file which I manage to do but only one paragraph was inserted in the text file.

Right now I am using the basic file command to do this and it hasn't worked I have searched online for other ways and none of the methods worked in my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalia")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text)

file = open("Research.txt", "w")
file.write(p.text)
file.close()
```

Thank You in Advanced!

Comment: Your `file.write` statement is not in the `for` loop

Comment: Your print is in a loop. Your file write is outside the loop and should only get the last value of p

Comment: Hello @Carcigenicate, could you show me how to syntax this? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your write operation is not in the loop. A simple solution would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalia")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
mytext = ""

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text)
    mytext += p.text

file = open("Research.txt", "w")
file.write(mytext)
file.close()
```

This Mostly works like your current code, but constructs a string in the loop and then writes it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Either it is a formatting error in your question, either your `f.write()` method is outside your *for loop*. The following code should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalia")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

with open("Research.txt", 'a') as f: # 'a' code stands for 'append'
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        f.write(f"{p.text}\n")
```

> NB: If you do not understand the `with open` statement, take a look at: [with-statement-in-python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)
>
> NB2: the *f-string* format (ie: `f"{p.text}\n"`) will only work with python3.6+. If you got a prior version, replace it by `"{}\n".format(p.text)`

Comment: This doesn't work with my specific page, but other work! Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted only prints the last paragraph since it's the last item the loop iterated over. The code below writes all the paragraphs:

```
with open("Research.txt", "w") as f:
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        f.write(p.text)
```